# Stop checkbox checked if qty is not greater than 1

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I stop the user from selecting the checkbox of a Grid row if the "Qty" of that Grid row is "0".
I have the code below but it still allows because as long as there is one row selected it allows the second and so on to be selected without changing the Qty value.
The selected row from each button above is then sent to form2.

```
public Test()
    {
        sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:/MyCedarDataConn/CedarPaints.db;");
        InitializeComponent();
        DataColumnCollection columns = Test.dt.Columns;
        DataColumn[] dataColumn = new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("ProdCode"), new DataColumn("Product"),  new DataColumn("Pack"), new DataColumn("t1"), new DataColumn("t2"), new DataColumn("Qty"), new DataColumn("WSale") };
        columns.AddRange(dataColumn);
    }

    private void BindDataGrid(string query)
    {

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ProdCode";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ProdCode";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ProdCode";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Product";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Product";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 160;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "t1";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "t1";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "t1";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 1;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Pack";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Pack";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Pack";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 50;


        this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "t2";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "t2";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "t2";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 1;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Qty";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Qty";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "Qty";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 50;

        this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "WSale";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "WSale";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "WSale";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 58;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##";

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        {
            HeaderText = "",
            Width = 30,
            Name = "checkBoxColumn"
        };

        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn);

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(sqlite))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {

                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    }
                }

            }
        }



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox4.Hide();
        pictureBox5.Hide();
        pictureBox6.Hide();
        pictureBox15.Hide();
        pictureBox16.Hide();
        pictureBox17.Hide();
        pictureBox18.Hide();
        pictureBox19.Hide();
        pan1.Show();
        dataGridView1.Show();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[28];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM PremiumSatinWallCoat");

        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[34];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM DesignWashableSheen");
       }
        if (i == 3)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[57];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM PolyurethaneEnamelTwinPack");
        }
        if (i == 4)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[55];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM PremiumPlasterPrimerSolventBased");
        }
        if (i == 5)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[57];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM SandingSealer");
        }
        if (i == 6)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[39];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, 0 as Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM FM");
        }
        if (i == 7)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[57];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, 0 as Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM ATC");
        }
        if (i == 8)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[57];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM Castors");
        }
        if (i == 9)
        {
            pan1.Image = imageList1.Images[13];
            BindDataGrid("SELECT ProdCode, Product, 0 as Pack, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, Qty, WSale FROM FGSP");
        }
    }



private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            string str1 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string str2 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToLower();
            string str3 = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            string str4 = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            string str5 = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string str6 = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            string str7 = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            //string style = "<style>.UppercaseWords</style>";

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                string str8 = dr["ProdCode"].ToString();
                string str9 = dr["Product"].ToString().ToLower();
                string str10 = dr["t1"].ToString();
                string str11 = dr["Pack"].ToString();
                string str12 = dr["t2"].ToString();
                string str13 = dr["Qty"].ToString();
                string str14 = dr["WSale"].ToString();

                if (str1 == str8 && str2 == str9 && str3 == str10 && str4 == str11 && str5 == str12 && str6 == str13 && str7 == str14) { }
                {
                            row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value = true;

                        }

                    }
                }



private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string value4 = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().ToLower() == "true")
        {
                dt.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value, UppercaseWords(value4), dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow[] dataRows = dt.Select(string.Format("ProdCode='{0}' and Product='{1}' and t1='{2}' and t2='{3}' and Pack='{4}' and Qty='{5}' and WSale='{6}'", dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value));

                foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataRows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(dataRow);
                }

            }
        }



 private void vButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataView dw = new DataView(dt);
        string[] cols = { "ProdCode", "Product", "t1", "t2", "Pack", "Qty", "WSale" };
        DataTable dt1 = dw.ToTable(true, cols);

        if (dt1.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select atleast one record");
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable filtereRecord = (from DataRow dr in dt1.Rows
                                       where dr["Qty"].ToString() != "0"
                                       select dr).CopyToDataTable();
            if (filtereRecord.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Form2 f = new Form2(dt1);
                f.ShowDialog();


            }
        }
    }
```

The screen:

[image: form 1]

[sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CoWb.png)

Comment: It looks like the added screenshot is for `Form2`, am I right? Nobody here can help fix your `Form2` if you don't include a single detail about it (such as what Grid definition it contains, etc). Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46600500/edit) and add enough detail about the Grid of `Form2` and about how/where that Row Checkbox is defined.

Comment: HI. the screenshot is datagridview1 from form1. The selected checkbox from this form is then sent to form2. However the user most of the times selects the checkbox but somehow forgets to change the "Qty" value.

Comment: Note the difference between your title and body: "qty is not greater than 1" (`qty <= 1`) and " if the Qty"of that Grid row is "0"" (`qty < 1`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CellBeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) event that occurs when edit mode starts for the selected cell.

```
Private Sub YourDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles YourDataGridView.CellBeginEdit

    Try
        With Me.YourDataGridView
            If .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "YourCheckBoxColumnName" AndAlso .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("YourQuantityColumnName").Value > 1 Then
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```